How to merge verticies by distance in particular area without full selection?
I want to merge verticies in particular area. For example, I have 2 subdivided cubes in one mesh, which I want to merge:

But I want to merge only this verticies (left part shifted for better visualization):

I can only select one row with alt+RMB, but in that case when I'm trying to merge verticies by distance I'm getting nothing, because merge working only in selected area. Usually, we can use unselected checkbox, but it's not an option, when you don't want to affect other parts of mesh. So, how can I merge this verticies if I can only select a part of it?
P.S. Sorry, I don't know how to formulate this question better.

you need to select the bottom vertices of the top mesh and the top vertices of the bottom mesh, then merge by distance, then you can increase the threshold in the Operator Box

@moonboots yes, I know, but as I mentioned, I can't do that. It's easy in this example, but I can't do this in more complex meshes.

could you please tell a bit more about the real case?

@moonboots, of course. High poly characters, created from parts - like torso, legs, arms, breast, head, etc... For examle, when I'm trying to connect arm it's not hard to select outer side, but armpit area is a hell for me. Even wireframe mode can't help, because of another mesh you see through it.

Maybe Select > Select Loops > Select Boundary Loop? then Merge by Distance

@moonboots unfortunately, not working at all.

I think you might be wanting to do Mesh > Delete > Limited Dissolve rather than merge by vertices, run that first to get rid of the redundant verts between the corners, then run merge by distance to join the corner verts.

You can make yourself a Geometry Nodes tool:

Then search for its name in F3 menu and F9 adjust the threshold:


Thank you very much! It works for me.

I think that this is a question more about selction techniques (which can be very sophisticated) than merging vertices.
For istance, after selecting some vertices, you can press Ctrl G to assign them to a new vertex group, then add and/or remove vertices from that group.
If in wireframe mode you get seleting an unwanted part of the mesh, you can hide it before selecting (H, Ctrl H, Alt H).
You can use Ctrl click and Shift Ctrl click to select Shortest Path and Shortest Path Areas of the mesh, Ctrl Plus and Minus to expand and contract the selection, ......
I suggest you to have a deep dive into the Select Menu in edit mode, you'll probably find one or more solutions to your needs.

Thank you. I used your solution with hiding verticies, but solution of Markus von Broady was published earlier and seems more elegant in my opinion. But I'm still appreciate your time.

No problem, I hope they were both useful.
